# Recursion with higher order functions

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I would like to understand the following example so it is crystal clear for me. Unfortunately, my head hangs on the line: .forEach (c => (node [c.id] = makeTree (categories, c.id))). can someone give me a hint?

```
let categories = [
  { id: 'animals', parent: null },
  { id: 'mammals', parent: 'animals' },
  { id: 'cats', parent: 'mammals' },
  { id: 'dogs', parent: 'mammals' },
  { id: 'chihuahua', parent: 'dogs' },
  { id: 'labrador', parent: 'dogs' },
  { id: 'persian', parent: 'cats' },
  { id: 'siamese', parent: 'cats' }
];

let makeTree = (categories, parent) => {
  let node = {};
  categories
    .filter(c => c.parent == parent)
    .forEach(c => (node[c.id] = makeTree(categories, c.id)));
  return node;
};

console.log(makeTree(categories, null));

expected:

{
  animals: {
    mammals: {
      dogs: {
        chihuahua: null
        labrador: null
      },
      cats: {
        persian: null
        siamese: null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get it but when writing the answer it's hard to explain it

Comment: What exactly is unclear about that line? It just creates a subtree of the categories remaining after the `filter`.

Comment: As Kevin said, it's hard to give an answer since the code is working, you just need to understand it. Sometimes, it's easier to understand code when it's not ES6, add many console logs and take time to read them attentively. https://jsfiddle.net/bcfj71ry/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can equivalently (and, imho, cleaner) be written with a normal loop and a conditional instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
function makeTree(categories, parent) {
  let node = {};
  for (const c of categories)
    if (c.parent == parent)
      node[c.id] = makeTree(categories, c.id);
  return node;
}
```

Now it's just an ordinary recursive function, nothing higher-order left.

Also, regarding the `forEach` callback specifically, that uses a totally unnecessary [grouping parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) in the [shorthand arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of properly writing it with a block body (since nothing needs to be returned from a `forEach` callback):

```
.forEach(c => {
  node[c.id] = makeTree(categories, c.id);
});
```

Comment: As a follow-up on the last paragraph, I personally recommend using the shorthand arrow syntax only when the intention is to return something from the callback. As Bergi correctly explains, nothing is being returned, so using curly braces instead of the shorthand confirms that intention.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make more sense?

Fiddle proof: https://jsfiddle.net/gz6uyodw/2/

```
function makeTree(categories, parent) {
  let node = {};
  const filteredArr = categories.filter(c => c.parent === parent);
  console.log('level arr', filteredArr)
  for (let obj of filteredArr) {
    const nodeToAppend = makeTree(categories, obj.id);
    console.log('node to append:', nodeToAppend)
    node[obj.id] = nodeToAppend;
  }
  return node;
}

console.log(makeTree(categories, null));
```

Basicaly, you are preparing a filtered array which you are preparing a level for, for the first level you have animals which contain a second filteredArr level which are mamals, mamals have groups which are dogs and there will be 2 objects in the array (added an extra one to have different filteredArr for cats and dogs) for them and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is just a fancy dressed loop.

What makes recursion hard to understand is that part of the loop is hidden from you.

The hidden part is called call stack. Understand  call stack and you understand recursion.

```js
function makeTree(categories, parent) {
  let node = {};
  const stack = [{ parent, node }];
  while (stack.length) {
    const { parent, node } = stack.pop();
    for (const category of categories) {
      if (category.parent === parent) {
        const subnode = {};
        node[category.id] = subnode;
        stack.push({
          parent: category.id,
          node: subnode
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return node;
}

let categories = [
  { id: 'animals', parent: null },
  { id: 'mammals', parent: 'animals' },
  { id: 'cats', parent: 'mammals' },
  { id: 'dogs', parent: 'mammals' },
  { id: 'chihuahua', parent: 'dogs' },
  { id: 'labrador', parent: 'dogs' },
  { id: 'persian', parent: 'cats' },
  { id: 'siamese', parent: 'cats' }
];

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(makeTree(categories, null), null, 2)}</pre>`
```

A little lengthier but exactly the way how recursion works:

```
function makeTree(categories, parent) {
  const stack = [{ parent }];
  let subnode; // the return value
  call: while (stack.length) {
    let { parent, node, i, c } = stack.pop();
    if (!node) {
      node = {};
      i = 0;
    } else {
      node[c.id] = subnode;
    }
    for (; i < categories.length; i++) {
      const category = categories[i];
      if (category.parent === parent) {
        stack.push({
          parent,
          node,
          i: i+1,
          c: category
        });
        stack.push({
          parent: category.id
        });
        continue call;
      }
    }
    subnode = node;
  }
  return subnode;
}
```

Comment: Notice that this is not exactly equivalent to what the recursive call stack does though, where multiple loops over `categories` are active at the same time. Also your code does the `node[category.id] = subnode;` before the element is processed - as it doesn't know how to "return" from a recursive call.

Comment: @Bergi I was wondering if someone notices it; It's nice to know that there are people who understand recursion deeply ;). I'll add another piece of code, lengthier but more inline to how recursion works

Comment: SCNR to make it exactly how recursion works, with a distinction which stack frame is continued :-)

Comment: @Bergi nice :-)